# Using Infinite scroll when someone else made a new comments

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a wall using infinite scroll, and the posts on the wall are ordered by the time of last comment.

Let's say:
There are 2 users, A and B. 
Initially the wall has 10 posts and the infinite scroll adds 10 more posts every time.

Scenario:
A are viewing the initial 10 posts on the wall. Meanwhile, B have triggered the infinite scroll once, so he can view the next 10 posts as well. Then B decides to add a comment for the 11th post. After B added the comment, A triggered the infinite scroll. However A would not see the same 11-20 posts as B saw. A would see 2 same posts (the 10th and 11th). Because the former 11th post had a new comment and became the new latest post.

I am wondering is there any way to overcome this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for the interface to reload on A and B's browser to reflect the changes in comments / latest post???

Comment: Hi Seth. Currently I am using a timestamp to remember when users begin to view the wall. The infinite scroll will not show any posts contain comments which are newer than the timestamp. This will prevent showing same posts, but the drawback is A will never see "the 11th post" unless he reload the page. So I am looking for any possible solutions can do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a heartbeat which asks for updates? Might be useful to use Firebug to check how Facebook handles this problem.